# convert MSProject.Task to System.Tables?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to convert MSProject.Project that I am reading from an .mpp file to a DataSet?

Or it is impossible is the first time I use this tool from MSProject.Project

```
public new string Load(string fileName)
    {
        MSProject.ApplicationClass app = null;
        string retVal = "";
        List<MSProject.Task> tasks = new List<MSProject.Task>();
        DataSet Datos = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            // execute the Microsoft Project Application
            app = new MSProject.ApplicationClass();

            // Do not display Microsoft Project
            app.Visible = false;

            // open the project file.
            if (app.FileOpen(fileName, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
            {
                // go through all the open projects--there should only be one
                foreach (MSProject.Project proj in app.Projects)
                {
                    // go through all the tasks in the project
                    foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                    {
                        // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist
                        Datos.Tables.Add(task);
                        //tasks.Add(task);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = "The MS Project file " + fileName + " could not be opened.";
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = "Could not process the MS Project file " + fileName + "." + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace;
        }

        // close the application if is was opened.
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.Quit(MSProject.PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

I already managed to pass it to a `list<>` but it would work better to have it in a DataSet

It is the section that I have commented here

```
foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                    {
                        // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist
                        Datos.Tables.Add(task);
                        //tasks.Add(task);
                    }
```

The error is as follows:

> Argument 1: cannot be converted from 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: There is nothing built-in. You need to create columns in the DataTable, then you could loop through tasks, copying task properties into the row's fields. Not too much code.

Comment: Where could I find an example of what you mention?